# Run multiple functions at millisecond intervals in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I need to call multiple functions(200+) from different modules(5 ~ 10) for every millisecond to get value and write to a log. As of now I am using loop to call 200 functions but I am not getting the desired number of entries. What is the best way to do this? Shared below a code snippet(not exact code but my design will look like this)

```
std::ofstream logStream;
while (stop)
{
    for (int moduleIdx = 0; moduleIdx < moduleSize; moduleIdx++)
    {
        for (int fnIdx = 0; fnIdx < module[moduleIdx].totalFns(); fnIdx++)
        {
            std::string output;
            module[moduleIdx]->fn[fnIdx](output);
            logStream << moduleIdx << "," << fnIdx << "," << output << "\n";
        }
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
}
logStream.close();
```

Comment: unclear how you know that with your code you are "not getting the desired number of entries." when all you have is "not exact code but my design will look like this" .... please post a [mcve]

Comment: `sleep_for(1ms)` will get a 1ms pause after each run, not run it at fixed times. And anyway, if you don't have a real time operating system, all sleeps will be for **at least** the requested time. Could be much longer if the computer is busy.

Comment: have you looked at the `std::async` ? you are calling each function inside a simple loop in a blocked manner, so you won't get benefits of multi-core.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran On the other hand, starting up to 200 threads simultaneously will put a serious drain on the system. Especially if they start to compete for the same resources.

Comment: Not suggesting to start 200 threads simultaneously. Instead only suggesting to look at asynchronous model, certainly its not an one-line answer situation :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, the timer resolution is 15.6 ms by default, so your call to `sleep_for()` will take at least 15.6 ms. You can increase the timer resolution with `timeGetDevCaps()` and `timeBeginPeriod()`. [See the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep)

Another option is to remove the sleep, check the timestamp (use a timer with greater accuracy than 1 ms), and call the functions after 1 ms has elapsed.